# Advice on keeping Ec2 free tier - really free

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a question similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/326168/what-is-the-true-cost-of-amazons-ec2-free-tier).

I've taken a first foray into Ec2 - I expect really really low usage and have no power user requirements, and so I thought that the free instance would be ideal.

All I have done so far is bring up the instance, and `yum update` it. I checked the billing estimator, and it already seems to think that that I am accruing charges. it's not much, but I still feel slightly like I'm being nickel and dime'd - wondered if anyone had any guidance on keeping a free instance really 'free'

Thanks, Ace

Comment: You fired up a micro instance, yes? Which billing estimator are you looking at?

Comment: What OS did you pick? Note that you can deploy with RHEL but it isn't free. Pick a basic Linux (LAMP) AMI and you'll be fine.

Comment: I picked the AMI that was free tier eligable , the billing page says i'm accruing charges based on usage, but other than having logged in a few times,  i haven't done anything much with it

Comment: I've shut this instance down. I will try again with another one and record precisley what I do. We'll see what happens. Thanks for the responses

Comment: @phatmanace what was your update? I am also encountering this. I on the other hand, just uploaded a simple website template on it but looks like I'm being charged the same amount every month.

Comment: @johhnyq: some time ago, I moved to digital ocean and haven't looked back. It costs me $5 a month. Always. Without variantion

Answer (score 1):

Free tier of EC2 equates to:

- 1 Micro Linux(Acceptable OSs) and 1 Micro Windows(Running Server 2012 base).
- You receive 15GB of data transfer out across all AWS services.
- 1 Elastic IP per running instance and they must be bound to the instance.
- 30GB of provisioned Elastic Block Storage
- 2 million I/Os on those EBS devices
- Elastic Load Balancer with 15GB of data processiong.

Also AWS Free tier information can be found here https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

What components are you being charged for?

The free tier includes enough compute time to run a micro instance and 15gb of data transfer. If you create snapshots of your machine, turn on detail monitoring, add an elastic ip, or do a number of other things, you might incur extra charges.

You can see your billing break-down here:
https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary